# SCP V.4.9.6 - after creating ROI, Warning: The following signature will be excluded if using Maximum Likelihood

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, land-classification

I am creating ROI in Clouds using "create a ROI" (polygon) and this warning often shows after i save the ROI. Since the warning says that it will affect the Maximum Likelihood, that is why i delete the ROI that i created. But sometimes there is no warning.

Any advice why this happened? is it the size of the polygon i created? is it necessary to delete it?

[image: Attached]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ROI is too small (or too homogeneous) for the Maximum Likelihood algorithm because that ROI has a singular covariance matrix. You should create larger ROIs or don’t use the Maximum Likelihood algorithm in the classification process.

Check out (FAQ: 7.4.1.):
[FAQ - SCP-Plugin](http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to satellite download using SCP plugin only and don't forget to download associated XML files if available, I notice if data downloaded or imported from the external sources are lack in essential statistic files.

Comment: The problem has already been identified (see accepted answer) two years ago, so it seems pointless to add a guessing answer. Thanks for trying either way and please check out the [tour].